# Use Shopify API request to get all products using JavaScript on custom website

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, shopify, e-commerce

I have a website custom built on node.js and I want to be able to get all of my products in a GET request. The shopify [buy-button](https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/sell-online/buy-button/create-buy-button) is not allowing me to have all of the products brought into the page at once (it has pagination), which is preventing me from properly filtering through all of the products (I have custom filters on the site).

Thus, [based on a post that I read](https://community.shopify.com/c/Shopify-Design/One-product-page-with-multiple-products-buy-buttons/td-p/210720) in shopify forums I'm looking to do something like the following:

```
<div class="wps-buy-button" id='[product-id]-[var-id]' data-id='[product-id]' data-var='[var-id]'></div>
```

This will allow me to filter through all of the different shopify products. **However**, the difficult part is now getting the `product-id` and `var-id` fields. One would think that simply going to **Products => All Products => Export** would be enough, but they don't list the product-id and var-id in that.

I've tried using the [Shopify-Buy npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/shopify-buy#fetching-products), which looks like the following code, but am getting an ugly, unusable response:

So my question is, how can I get a response of all of my different Shopify products, either using an API, or whatever, without [having to use PH](https://community.shopify.com/c/Shopify-APIs-SDKs/How-to-get-all-product/m-p/139994)P, or pay for a [shopify plugin](https://apps.shopify.com/product-and-variant-ids) just to get product-ids and var-ids (I'm on [Shopify lite](https://www.shopify.com/lite) plan since I'm just plugging it into my existing platform).

**CODE:**

```
import Client from 'shopify-buy';

const client = Client.buildClient({
  domain: 'your-shop-name.myshopify.com',
  storefrontAccessToken: 'your-storefront-access-token'
});

// Fetch all products in your shop
client.product.fetchAll().then((products) => {
  // Do something with the products
  console.log(products);
});
```

**RESPONSE:**

```js
[ GraphModel {
    id: [Getter],
    handle: [Getter],
    description: [Getter],
    descriptionHtml: [Getter],
    updatedAt: [Getter],
    title: [Getter],
    image: [Getter],
    products: [Getter],
    refetchQuery: [Getter],
    type: [Getter],
    nextPageQueryAndPath: [Function],
    hasNextPage: false,
    hasPreviousPage: false,
    variableValues: { first: 20, productsFirst: 20 } },
  type: { name: 'CollectionConnection',
    kind: 'OBJECT',
    fieldBaseTypes: { edges: 'CollectionEdge', pageInfo: 'PageInfo' },
    implementsNode: false } ]
[ GraphModel {
    id: [Getter],
    availableForSale: [Getter],
    createdAt: [Getter],
    updatedAt: [Getter],
    descriptionHtml: [Getter],
    description: [Getter],
    handle: [Getter],
    productType: [Getter],
    title: [Getter],
    vendor: [Getter],
    publishedAt: [Getter],
    onlineStoreUrl: [Getter],
    options: [Getter],
    images: [Getter],
    variants: [Getter],
    refetchQuery: [Getter],
    type: [Getter],
    nextPageQueryAndPath: [Function],
    hasNextPage: { [Boolean: true] value: true },
    hasPreviousPage: false,
    variableValues: { first: 20, productsFirst: 20 } },
  GraphModel {
    id: [Getter],
    availableForSale: [Getter],
    createdAt: [Getter],
    updatedAt: [Getter],
    descriptionHtml: [Getter],
    description: [Getter],
    handle: [Getter],
    productType: [Getter],
    title: [Getter],
    vendor: [Getter],
    publishedAt: [Getter],
    onlineStoreUrl: [Getter],
    options: [Getter],
    images: [Getter],
    variants: [Getter],
    refetchQuery: [Getter],
    type: [Getter],
    nextPageQueryAndPath: [Function],
    hasNextPage: { [Boolean: true] value: true },
    hasPreviousPage: { [Boolean: true] value: true },
    variableValues: { first: 20, productsFirst: 20 } },
  GraphModel {
    id: [Getter],
    availableForSale: [Getter],
    createdAt: [Getter],
    updatedAt: [Getter],
    descriptionHtml: [Getter],
    description: [Getter],
    handle: [Getter],
    productType: [Getter],
    title: [Getter],
    vendor: [Getter],
    publishedAt: [Getter],
    onlineStoreUrl: [Getter],
    options: [Getter],
    images: [Getter],
    variants: [Getter],
    refetchQuery: [Getter],
    type: [Getter],
    nextPageQueryAndPath: [Function],
    hasNextPage: { [Boolean: true] value: true },
    hasPreviousPage: { [Boolean: true] value: true },
    variableValues: { first: 20, productsFirst: 20 } },
  GraphModel {
    id: [Getter],
    availableForSale: [Getter],
    createdAt: [Getter],
    updatedAt: [Getter],
    descriptionHtml: [Getter],
    description: [Getter],
    handle: [Getter],
    productType: [Getter],
    title: [Getter],
    vendor: [Getter],
    publishedAt: [Getter],
    onlineStoreUrl: [Getter],
    options: [Getter],
    images: [Getter],
    variants: [Getter],
    refetchQuery: [Getter],
    type: [Getter],
    nextPageQueryAndPath: [Function],
    hasNextPage: { [Boolean: true] value: true },
    hasPreviousPage: { [Boolean: true] value: true },
    variableValues: { first: 20, productsFirst: 20 } },
  GraphModel {
    id: [Getter],
    availableForSale: [Getter],
    createdAt: [Getter],
    updatedAt: [Getter],
    descriptionHtml: [Getter],
    description: [Getter],
    handle: [Getter],
    productType: [Getter],
    title: [Getter],
    vendor: [Getter],
    publishedAt: [Getter],
    onlineStoreUrl: [Getter],
    options: [Getter],
    images: [Getter],
    variants: [Getter],
    refetchQuery: [Getter],
    type: [Getter],
    nextPageQueryAndPath: [Function],
    hasNextPage: { [Boolean: true] value: true },
    hasPreviousPage: { [Boolean: true] value: true },
    variableValues: { first: 20, productsFirst: 20 } },
  GraphModel {
    id: [Getter],
    availableForSale: [Getter],
    createdAt: [Getter],
    updatedAt: [Getter],
    descriptionHtml: [Getter],
    description: [Getter],
    handle: [Getter],
    productType: [Getter],
    title: [Getter],
    vendor: [Getter],
    publishedAt: [Getter],
    onlineStoreUrl: [Getter],
    options: [Getter],
    images: [Getter],
    variants: [Getter],
    refetchQuery: [Getter],
    type: [Getter],
    nextPageQueryAndPath: [Function],
    hasNextPage: { [Boolean: true] value: true },
    hasPreviousPage: { [Boolean: true] value: true },
    variableValues: { first: 20, productsFirst: 20 } },
  GraphModel {
    id: [Getter],
    availableForSale: [Getter],
    createdAt: [Getter],
    updatedAt: [Getter],
    descriptionHtml: [Getter],
    description: [Getter],
    handle: [Getter],
    productType: [Getter],
    title: [Getter],
    vendor: [Getter],
    publishedAt: [Getter],
    onlineStoreUrl: [Getter],
    options: [Getter],
    images: [Getter],
    variants: [Getter],
    refetchQuery: [Getter],
    type: [Getter],
    nextPageQueryAndPath: [Function],
    hasNextPage: { [Boolean: true] value: true },
    hasPreviousPage: { [Boolean: true] value: true },
    variableValues: { first: 20, productsFirst: 20 } },
  GraphModel {
    id: [Getter],
    availableForSale: [Getter],
    createdAt: [Getter],
    updatedAt: [Getter],
    descriptionHtml: [Getter],
    description: [Getter],
    handle: [Getter],
    productType: [Getter],
    title: [Getter],
    vendor: [Getter],
    publishedAt: [Getter],
    onlineStoreUrl: [Getter],
    options: [Getter],
    images: [Getter],
    variants: [Getter],
    refetchQuery: [Getter],
    type: [Getter],
    nextPageQueryAndPath: [Function],
    hasNextPage: { [Boolean: true] value: true },
    hasPreviousPage: { [Boolean: true] value: true },
    variableValues: { first: 20, productsFirst: 20 } },
  GraphModel {
    id: [Getter],
    availableForSale: [Getter],
    createdAt: [Getter],
    updatedAt: [Getter],
    descriptionHtml: [Getter],
    description: [Getter],
    handle: [Getter],
    productType: [Getter],
    title: [Getter],
    vendor: [Getter],
    publishedAt: [Getter],
    onlineStoreUrl: [Getter],
    options: [Getter],
    images: [Getter],
    variants: [Getter],
    refetchQuery: [Getter],
    type: [Getter],
    nextPageQueryAndPath: [Function],
    hasNextPage: { [Boolean: true] value: true },
    hasPreviousPage: { [Boolean: true] value: true },
    variableValues: { first: 20, productsFirst: 20 } },
  GraphModel {
    id: [Getter],
    availableForSale: [Getter],
    createdAt: [Getter],
    updatedAt: [Getter],
    descriptionHtml: [Getter],
    description: [Getter],
    handle: [Getter],
    productType: [Getter],
    title: [Getter],
    vendor: [Getter],
    publishedAt: [Getter],
    onlineStoreUrl: [Getter],
    options: [Getter],
    images: [Getter],
    variants: [Getter],
    refetchQuery: [Getter],
    type: [Getter],
    nextPageQueryAndPath: [Function],
    hasNextPage: { [Boolean: true] value: true },
    hasPreviousPage: { [Boolean: true] value: true },
    variableValues: { first: 20, productsFirst: 20 } },
  GraphModel {
    id: [Getter],
    availableForSale: [Getter],
    createdAt: [Getter],
    updatedAt: [Getter],
    descriptionHtml: [Getter],
    description: [Getter],
    handle: [Getter],
    productType: [Getter],
    title: [Getter],
    vendor: [Getter],
    publishedAt: [Getter],
    onlineStoreUrl: [Getter],
    options: [Getter],
    images: [Getter],
    variants: [Getter],
    refetchQuery: [Getter],
    type: [Getter],
    nextPageQueryAndPath: [Function],
    hasNextPage: { [Boolean: true] value: true },
    hasPreviousPage: { [Boolean: true] value: true },
    variableValues: { first: 20, productsFirst: 20 } },
  GraphModel {
    id: [Getter],
    availableForSale: [Getter],
    createdAt: [Getter],
    updatedAt: [Getter],
    descriptionHtml: [Getter],
    description: [Getter],
    handle: [Getter],
    productType: [Getter],
    title: [Getter],
    vendor: [Getter],
    publishedAt: [Getter],
    onlineStoreUrl: [Getter],
    options: [Getter],
    images: [Getter],
    variants: [Getter],
    refetchQuery: [Getter],
    type: [Getter],
    nextPageQueryAndPath: [Function],
    hasNextPage: { [Boolean: true] value: true },
    hasPreviousPage: { [Boolean: true] value: true },
    variableValues: { first: 20, productsFirst: 20 } },
  GraphModel {
    id: [Getter],
    availableForSale: [Getter],
    createdAt: [Getter],
    updatedAt: [Getter],
    descriptionHtml: [Getter],
    description: [Getter],
    handle: [Getter],
    productType: [Getter],
    title: [Getter],
    vendor: [Getter],
    publishedAt: [Getter],
    onlineStoreUrl: [Getter],
    options: [Getter],
    images: [Getter],
    variants: [Getter],
    refetchQuery: [Getter],
    type: [Getter],
    nextPageQueryAndPath: [Function],
    hasNextPage: { [Boolean: true] value: true },
    hasPreviousPage: { [Boolean: true] value: true },
    variableValues: { first: 20, productsFirst: 20 } },
  GraphModel {
    id: [Getter],
    availableForSale: [Getter],
    createdAt: [Getter],
    updatedAt: [Getter],
    descriptionHtml: [Getter],
    description: [Getter],
    handle: [Getter],
    productType: [Getter],
    title: [Getter],
    vendor: [Getter],
    publishedAt: [Getter],
    onlineStoreUrl: [Getter],
    options: [Getter],
    images: [Getter],
    variants: [Getter],
    refetchQuery: [Getter],
    type: [Getter],
    nextPageQueryAndPath: [Function],
    hasNextPage: { [Boolean: true] value: true },
    hasPreviousPage: { [Boolean: true] value: true },
    variableValues: { first: 20, productsFirst: 20 } },
  GraphModel {
    id: [Getter],
    availableForSale: [Getter],
    createdAt: [Getter],
    updatedAt: [Getter],
    descriptionHtml: [Getter],
    description: [Getter],
    handle: [Getter],
    productType: [Getter],
    title: [Getter],
    vendor: [Getter],
    publishedAt: [Getter],
    onlineStoreUrl: [Getter],
    options: [Getter],
    images: [Getter],
    variants: [Getter],
    refetchQuery: [Getter],
    type: [Getter],
    nextPageQueryAndPath: [Function],
    hasNextPage: { [Boolean: true] value: true },
    hasPreviousPage: { [Boolean: true] value: true },
    variableValues: { first: 20, productsFirst: 20 } },
  GraphModel {
    id: [Getter],
    availableForSale: [Getter],
    createdAt: [Getter],
    updatedAt: [Getter],
    descriptionHtml: [Getter],
    description: [Getter],
    handle: [Getter],
    productType: [Getter],
    title: [Getter],
    vendor: [Getter],
    publishedAt: [Getter],
    onlineStoreUrl: [Getter],
    options: [Getter],
    images: [Getter],
    variants: [Getter],
    refetchQuery: [Getter],
    type: [Getter],
    nextPageQueryAndPath: [Function],
    hasNextPage: { [Boolean: true] value: true },
    hasPreviousPage: { [Boolean: true] value: true },
    variableValues: { first: 20, productsFirst: 20 } },
  GraphModel {
    id: [Getter],
    availableForSale: [Getter],
    createdAt: [Getter],
    updatedAt: [Getter],
    descriptionHtml: [Getter],
    description: [Getter],
    handle: [Getter],
    productType: [Getter],
    title: [Getter],
    vendor: [Getter],
    publishedAt: [Getter],
    onlineStoreUrl: [Getter],
    options: [Getter],
    images: [Getter],
    variants: [Getter],
    refetchQuery: [Getter],
    type: [Getter],
    nextPageQueryAndPath: [Function],
    hasNextPage: { [Boolean: true] value: true },
    hasPreviousPage: { [Boolean: true] value: true },
    variableValues: { first: 20, productsFirst: 20 } },
  GraphModel {
    id: [Getter],
    availableForSale: [Getter],
    createdAt: [Getter],
    updatedAt: [Getter],
    descriptionHtml: [Getter],
    description: [Getter],
    handle: [Getter],
    productType: [Getter],
    title: [Getter],
    vendor: [Getter],
    publishedAt: [Getter],
    onlineStoreUrl: [Getter],
    options: [Getter],
    images: [Getter],
    variants: [Getter],
    refetchQuery: [Getter],
    type: [Getter],
    nextPageQueryAndPath: [Function],
    hasNextPage: { [Boolean: true] value: true },
    hasPreviousPage: { [Boolean: true] value: true },
    variableValues: { first: 20, productsFirst: 20 } },
  GraphModel {
    id: [Getter],
    availableForSale: [Getter],
    createdAt: [Getter],
    updatedAt: [Getter],
    descriptionHtml: [Getter],
    description: [Getter],
    handle: [Getter],
    productType: [Getter],
    title: [Getter],
    vendor: [Getter],
    publishedAt: [Getter],
    onlineStoreUrl: [Getter],
    options: [Getter],
    images: [Getter],
    variants: [Getter],
    refetchQuery: [Getter],
    type: [Getter],
    nextPageQueryAndPath: [Function],
    hasNextPage: { [Boolean: true] value: true },
    hasPreviousPage: { [Boolean: true] value: true },
    variableValues: { first: 20, productsFirst: 20 } },
  GraphModel {
    id: [Getter],
    availableForSale: [Getter],
    createdAt: [Getter],
    updatedAt: [Getter],
    descriptionHtml: [Getter],
    description: [Getter],
    handle: [Getter],
    productType: [Getter],
    title: [Getter],
    vendor: [Getter],
    publishedAt: [Getter],
    onlineStoreUrl: [Getter],
    options: [Getter],
    images: [Getter],
    variants: [Getter],
    refetchQuery: [Getter],
    type: [Getter],
    nextPageQueryAndPath: [Function],
    hasNextPage: true,
    hasPreviousPage: { [Boolean: true] value: true },
    variableValues: { first: 20, productsFirst: 20 } },
  type: { name: 'ProductConnection',
    kind: 'OBJECT',
    fieldBaseTypes: { edges: 'ProductEdge', pageInfo: 'PageInfo' },
    implementsNode: false } ]
```

Comment: As you already have a NodeJS application, just use the Rest API. To ease the process you can use [Shopify API NodeJS module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/shopify-api-node)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the Shopify Product Id and Product Variant ID, you can use Shopify REST API. Since, you already have the NodeJS application you can use the [Shopify API Node.js Module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/shopify-api-node). Just fetch all products, pass fetched data to frontend and then use the scripts mentioned in your question to render Shopify Buy button.

Sample code to get all products

```
const Shopify = require('shopify-api-node');

const shopify = new Shopify({
    shopName: 'store-url.myshopify.com',
    apiKey: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    password: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    autoLimit: true
});



shopify.product.count()
    .then(async (count) => {
        if (count > 0) {

            const pages = Math.ceil(count / 250);
            let products = [];

            for (i = 0; i < pages; i++) {
                // use Promise.all instead of waiting for each response
                const result = await shopify.product.list({
                    limit: 250,
                    page: i + 1,
                    fields: 'id, variants'
                });
                products = products.concat(result);
            }
            // products array should have all the products. Includes id and variants
            console.log(products);
        }
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });
```

For better performance, consider saving products in database and update information periodically.

[Shopify REST API](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/products/product)

Answer (score 1):

This solution works with `shopify-api-node` in 2023:

```js
    let products: IPaginatedResult<IProduct> = []
    let page_info: string | undefined = undefined

    // Get all products
    // page_info is the next page ID to fetch
    // https://shopify.dev/docs/api/usage/pagination-rest
    do {
        const newProducts = await shopify.product.list({
            limit: 250, // max is 250
            page_info
        })

        products = [...products, ...newProducts]
        page_info = newProducts.nextPageParameters?.page_info
    } while (page_info)
    
   return products
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to accomplish it without using Storefront key or Admin Key.
Here is the answer :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/77309445/17860991